# Laravel 5, self reference hasone not work in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

All
I have Invoice model, and self reference

```php
\\Invoice Model
public function parentInvoice()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice', 'id', 'parent_invoice_id');
}
```

for test in web.php it's work

```php
Route::get('self', function () {
$parent = Invoice::find(132);
$children = $parent->parentInvoice->invoice_date;
echo $children;
// 2018-06-08 - it's work
});
```

but on blade don't work :( Why?

```php
not work! - <b>Date:</b>&nbsp; {{$invoice->parentInvoice->invoice_date)}} <br /><br />

it's work - <div class="header">Korekta faktury nr {{ $invoice->invoice_date 
   }}</div> 

Error: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Please help :(

This is my function on Invoice model:

```php
private function generateCreditnoteInvoiceChangeData()
    {
        $config = InvoiceConfig::find(1);
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView(
            'pdf.creditnote_invoice_change_data',
            array(
                'config' => $config,
                'invoice' => $this
            )
        );

        return $pdf;
    }
```

Comment: may be because in your test your variable is named `$parent` and in your blade you are using `$invoice`, can you confirm that the variable names are correct?

Comment: `$invoice` is probably not an object (or `$parentInvoice`). so check them

Comment: This is my function on Invoice model: `private function generateCreditnoteInvoiceChangeData()
    {
        $config = InvoiceConfig::find(1);
        $pdf = \PDF::loadView(
            'pdf.creditnote_invoice_change_data',
            array(
                'config' => $config,
                'invoice' => $this
            )
        );

        return $pdf;
    }`

Comment: i'm sure that `$invoice` is an object